# Употребление слова "всеми"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Знакомый употребил слово "всеми" в странном, на мой взгляд, контексте: "Мы всеми поедем". Он был уверен, что так говорить можно. Позднее, мне доводилось неоднократно слышать подобное употребление данного слова, пока проживала в Воронеже: "Всеми смотрим на экран", "Будем делать всеми" и т.п. Однажды, даже от диктора местного телевидения. Как-то неприятно звучит, и, думаю, что неправильно.

Answer (score 2):

Красивая и удобная форма, но, увы, не нормативная. 
Возможно "мы все поедем".

Приводимый же вами вариант я бы рекомендовал только для передачи диалектной речи или просторечий героя в художественных текстах.

Answer (score 1):

*Всеми*, во-первых, словоформа местоименного слова *все*, значение которого, я думаю, вам понятно. Мне кажется такое употребление либо полностью неправильным. По крайней мере, оно выходит за рамки литературной нормы.

Просклонять слово можно [здесь](http://morpher.ru/Demo.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Я никогда такого не слышал. Если повторяется в тех местах, можно поискать в словарях среднерусских говоров - возможно, где-то и зафиксировано. Разумеется, перенимать это не нужно. Нормативное выражение для таких случаев: "всей семьёй" ("все вместе").

Answer (score 0):

Мы все — нами всеми; они все — ими всеми. Не надо смешивать и смешить людей. Интересно бы отследить, случается ли в речи этого господина правильное употребление **всеми** и в каких оборотах.